# Conflict of two javascript functions

Tags: javascript, flask

I am using Flask. The template for app requires following functions of Jquery for smart links in master file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/libs/jquery/jquery.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- SmartMenus jQuery plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.smartmenus.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- SmartMenus jQuery init -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#main-menu').smartmenus({
          subMenusSubOffsetX: 1,
          subMenusSubOffsetY: -8
        });
      });
    </script>
```

whereas,following javascript code requires on the extended pages.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>


   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
       buttons: [
           'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
       ]
   } );
} );
   </script>
```

If I comment the first block of code on master file, then below code is effective on my table, otherwise, second block isn't effective. :(

Kindly help how these two functions should be integrated?

Answer (score 0):

Load jQuery once and only once.

Loading jQuery, adding plugins, then loading jQuery again will erase the plugins.

Do not use obsolete, unsupported versions of jQuery with [known security vulnerabilities](https://snyk.io/test/npm/jquery/1.12.4).

Comment: In case, I have master file which is later extended by other pages. How can I ensure that Jquery is loaded once ?

Comment: Given you said that you were loading jQuery in the master file … don't load it anywhere except the master file!

Comment: I tried coping the second block in the master file, then first block doesn't work ? Is there any conflicting library as one is downloaded to local system, and second one is loaded online.

Comment: I have no idea what you just did, but it doesn't sound like you removed the line that loads jQuery from the non-master file.

Comment: can you please update the function such that both two functions; $('#example').DataTable and  $('#main-menu').smartmenus({ are in the same block ? I think I am making some mistake.

Comment: No, that's a completely different problem to the one you asked about.

Comment: What do you suggest then? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: The same time I've suggested all along. Don't load jQuery in the non-master file!!